# How to understand SIGSTOP is delivered?

Tags: c, linux, signals

My problem is handling SIGSTOP. I know SIGSTOP cannot be catched, handled and blocked but in some place of code, if SIGSTOP signal is delivered, execution must continue. I understand that I need to signal my process with SIGCONT but how can i understand SIGSTOP is delivered? Is there has to be another process that constantly sending SIGCONT? Is it must be external process?

Comment: how do you check for signal arrival? show us the code.

Comment: But why does your code receive SIGSTOP? There must be logic/reason behind it (and it doesn't appear randomly) right? Because SIGSTOP isn't something that typically a process receives unexpectedly. And that's where you need to put the SIGCONT logic too - possibly in a separate process than the one that sends SIGSTOP.

Answer (score 1):

Your process cannot detect SIGSTOP any more than it can detect SIGKILL.  The way that a process detects that it has received a signal is by receiving a notification via a signal handler (or equivalent, such as `signalfd` on Linux).  Since SIGSTOP cannot be caught, your process cannot receive any notification of it.

You can use an external process to send it SIGCONT if you like, but perhaps it's a good time to question why your process is receiving SIGSTOP when that is unwanted.  If this is purely precautionary, it's probably not worth worrying about unless your software is highly safety or security critical, in which case you may want to run it as a separate user to restrict who can signal it.

Comment: In somewhere on my code section, there is a critical section, that must not be interrupted by SIGSTOP. At that calculation, I need to ignore SIGSTOP. Is it a good choice sending signal to another process before going critical section. So the other process will know I need to be continue and send signal but I'm not sure since signals are async.

Comment: Is it actually likely that your process is going to receive SIGSTOP?  Why is it being sent?  That's the thing you should address.  If it's just that you're worried about it just in case, don't worry.  Most developers don't consider the random unexpected signal case because it doesn't matter.

Comment: @yellw Your process won't know whether it has received SIGSTOP, there is no way around being stopped by it.

The broader answer is that when someone on the system is capable of sending a SIGSTOP then the process is unconditionally stopped by the kernel (and will continue when the process is sent a SIGCONT).